# Not testing for stationarity in a panel data set

Tags: hypothesis-testing, panel-data, stationarity

Currently, I am analyzing a panel data set (different individuals over time) using panel data models with the lagged dependent variable as an explanatory variable. In this case the stationarity assumption is pretty important (since therefore we model the absolute value of the coefficient of the lagged dependent variable to be smaller than one). I was told that it is not necessary to explicitly test for the stationarity of the panel data set since the variables seem to fluctuate around a constant mean and it is a real-life data set. However, does someone know of any argument against testing for stationarity, and just using the data as it is, especially in a panel data setting? Citing different papers who do not use a specific test for it would not suffice as an answer in my opinion.